# ffmpeg: capture area outside screen size

Tags: ffmpeg

`man ffmpeg` has this:

```
X11 grabbing
   Grab the X11 display with ffmpeg via

           ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mpg

   0.0 is display.screen number of your X11 server, same as the DISPLAY environment variable.

           ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 /tmp/out.mpg

   0.0 is display.screen number of your X11 server, same as the DISPLAY environment variable. 10 is the x-offset and 20 the y-offset for the grabbing.
```

All the following commands except the last one work:

```
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+20,30 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+30,40 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+50,50 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+100,200 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+100,500 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
```

The output of the last command, the one that doesn't work, is this:

```
$ sleep 5s && ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+100,500 ~/"$(date +%H%M%S)".mpg
ffmpeg version N-79139-gde1a0d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
  libavcodec     57. 30.100 / 57. 30.100
  libavformat    57. 29.101 / 57. 29.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 40.102 /  6. 40.102
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[x11grab @ 0x3975f00] Capture area 352x288 at position 100.500 outside the screen size 1366x768
:0.0+100,500: Invalid argument
$
```

Can someone please help me fix the last command so that I can capture *any* area of my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen has a height of 768 pixels. Your capture area has a height of 288 pixels. Your y offset is 500 pixels. 288+500=788. This exceeds your screen height. With capture area height of 288 the max y offset is 480.